Alpine.js 3.x and Chart.js Integration Error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'save')"
I'm working on a Laravel project where I use Alpine.js for interactivity and Chart.js for data visualization. My setup works fine with Alpine.js 2.8.2, but when I upgrade to Alpine.js 3.x, I encounter the following error:
chart.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'save')
    at Ie (chart.js:19:18331)
    at An._drawDataset (chart.js:19:98188)
    at An._drawDatasets (chart.js:19:97819)
    at An.draw (chart.js:19:97350)
    at chart.js:13:6948
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at xt._update (chart.js:13:6727)
    at chart.js:13:6620

Relevant Code:
Here's the relevant part of my Blade template with the JavaScript initialization:
@extends('admin.layouts.app')

@section('vendor-styles')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('plugins/flatpickr/flatpickr.min.css') }}">
@endsection

@section('breadcrumbs')
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-700">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
@endsection

@section('content')
    <div x-data="dashboard()" x-init="init()">
        <!-- Time Range Filter -->
        <div class="bg-white p-4 rounded shadow mb-4">
            <div class="flex space-x-4 mb-4">
                <button @click="timeRange = 'today'; customRange = false"
                        :class="{ 'bg-blue-600 text-white': timeRange === 'today', 'bg-gray-200 text-gray-800': timeRange !== 'today' }"
                        class="p-2 rounded">Hôm nay
                </button>
                <button @click="timeRange = 'thisWeek'; customRange = false"
                        :class="{ 'bg-blue-600 text-white': timeRange === 'thisWeek', 'bg-gray-200 text-gray-800': timeRange !== 'thisWeek' }"
                        class="p-2 rounded">Tuần này
                </button>
                <button @click="timeRange = 'thisMonth'; customRange = false"
                        :class="{ 'bg-blue-600 text-white': timeRange === 'thisMonth', 'bg-gray-200 text-gray-800': timeRange !== 'thisMonth' }"
                        class="p-2 rounded">Tháng này
                </button>
                <button @click="timeRange = 'thisYear'; customRange = false"
                        :class="{ 'bg-blue-600 text-white': timeRange === 'thisYear', 'bg-gray-200 text-gray-800': timeRange !== 'thisYear' }"
                        class="p-2 rounded">Năm này
                </button>
                <button @click="timeRange = 'custom'; customRange = true"
                        :class="{ 'bg-blue-600 text-white': timeRange === 'custom', 'bg-gray-200 text-gray-800': timeRange !== 'custom' }"
                        class="p-2 rounded">Khoảng thời gian
                </button>
            </div>
            <div x-show="customRange" class="flex space-x-4">
                <input x-ref="datepicker" class="p-2 bg-gray-200 rounded" placeholder="Chọn khoảng thời gian">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Sales Overview -->
        <div class="bg-white p-4 rounded shadow mb-4">
            <h2 class="text-xl font-semibold mb-2">Tổng quan</h2>
            <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-6">
                <div class="p-6 bg-green-100 rounded-lg shadow-md flex items-center">
                    <div class="flex-1">
                        <div class="text-lg font-medium text-green-800 flex items-center">
                            <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign mr-2"></i>
                            Tổng doanh thu
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-3xl font-bold text-green-900" x-text="totalSales.revenue"></div>
                    </div>
                    {{--                    <div class="text-green-600 flex items-center">--}}
                    {{--                        <i class="fas fa-arrow-up text-2xl"></i>--}}
                    {{--                        <span class="ml-1 text-xl font-semibold">15%</span>--}}
                    {{--                    </div>--}}
                </div>

                <div class="p-6 bg-blue-100 rounded-lg shadow-md flex items-center">
                    <div class="flex-1">
                        <div class="text-lg font-medium text-green-800 flex items-center">
                            <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign mr-2"></i>
                            Tổng chi phí
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-3xl font-bold text-green-900" x-text="totalSales.cost"></div>
                    </div>
                    {{--                    <div class="text-green-600 flex items-center">--}}
                    {{--                        <i class="fas fa-arrow-up text-2xl"></i>--}}
                    {{--                        <span class="ml-1 text-xl font-semibold">15%</span>--}}
                    {{--                    </div>--}}
                </div>

                <div class="p-6 bg-yellow-100 rounded-lg shadow-md flex items-center">
                    <div class="flex-1">
                        <div class="text-lg font-medium text-green-800 flex items-center">
                            <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign mr-2"></i>
                            Tổng lợi nhuận
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-3xl font-bold text-green-900" x-text="totalSales.profit"></div>
                    </div>
                    {{--                    <div class="text-green-600 flex items-center">--}}
                    {{--                        <i class="fas fa-arrow-up text-2xl"></i>--}}
                    {{--                        <span class="ml-1 text-xl font-semibold">15%</span>--}}
                    {{--                    </div>--}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Sales Chart -->
        <div class="bg-white p-4 rounded shadow mb-4">
            <h2 class="text-xl font-semibold mb-2">Biểu Đồ Kinh Doanh</h2>
            <canvas id="salesChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
        </div>

        <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 gap-4">
            <!-- Sales by Category Chart -->
            <div class="bg-white p-4 rounded shadow mb-4">
                <h2 class="text-xl font-semibold mb-2 text-center">Doanh Thu Theo Danh Mục Sản Phẩm</h2>
                <canvas id="categoryChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
            </div>

            <!-- Sales by Brand Chart -->
            <div class="bg-white p-4 rounded shadow mb-4">
                <h2 class="text-xl font-semibold mb-2 text-center">Doanh Thu Theo Hãng Sản Xuất</h2>
                <canvas id="brandChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Recent Orders -->
        <div class="bg-white p-4 rounded shadow mb-4">
            <h2 class="text-xl font-semibold mb-2">Đơn Hàng Gần Đây</h2>
            <table class="w-full text-left border-collapse">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="p-2 border-b">Mã Đơn Hàng</th>
                    <th class="p-2 border-b">Khách Hàng</th>
                    <th class="p-2 border-b">Trạng Thái</th>
                    <th class="p-2 border-b">Ngày Đặt</th>
                    <th class="p-2 border-b">Tổng tiền</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <template x-for="order in recentOrders" :key="order.id">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="p-2 border-b">
                            <a :href="order?.url" x-text="order?.order_code" class="text-blue-600"></a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="p-2 border-b" x-text="order?.customer.name"></td>
                        <td class="p-2 border-b" x-text="order?.status"></td>
                        <td class="p-2 border-b" x-text="order?.formatted_created_at"></td>
                        <td class="p-2 border-b" x-text="order?.amount"></td>
                    </tr>
                </template>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 gap-4">
            <!-- Top Selling Products -->
            <div class="bg-white p-4 rounded shadow mb-4">
                <h2 class="text-xl font-semibold mb-2">Top Sản Phẩm Bán Chạy</h2>
                <ul>
                    <template x-for="product in topProducts" :key="product.id">
                        <li class="border-b py-2">
                            <span x-text="product.name"></span> - <span x-text="product.total_sales"></span>
                        </li>
                    </template>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <!-- Inventory -->
            <div class="bg-white p-4 rounded shadow mb-4">
                <h2 class="text-xl font-semibold mb-2">Sản Phẩm Sắp Hết Hàng</h2>
                <table class="w-full text-left border-collapse">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="p-2 border-b">Tên Sản Phẩm</th>
                        <th class="p-2 border-b">Màu Sắc</th>
                        <th class="p-2 border-b">Số Lượng Còn Lại</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <template x-for="product in lowStockProducts" :key="product.id">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="p-2 border-b">
                                <a :href="product?.url" x-text="product?.product_name" class="text-blue-600"></a>
                            </td>
                            <td class="p-2 border-b" x-text="product?.color"></td>
                            <td class="p-2 border-b" x-text="product?.quantity"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </template>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 gap-4">
            <div class="bg-white p-4 rounded shadow mb-4">
                <h2 class="text-xl font-semibold mb-2">Trạng thái đơn hàng</h2>
                <table class="w-full text-left border-collapse">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="p-2 border-b">Trạng Thái</th>
                        <th class="p-2 border-b">Số Đơn</th>
                        <th class="p-2 border-b">Tổng Doanh Thu</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <template x-for="(groupStatus, index) in orderByStatus" :key="index">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="p-2 border-b" x-text="groupStatus?.status"></td>
                            <td class="p-2 border-b" x-text="groupStatus?.count"></td>
                            <td class="p-2 border-b" x-text="groupStatus?.revenue"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </template>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection

@section('vendor-scripts')
    <script src="{{ asset('plugins/chartjs/chart.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('plugins/flatpickr/flatpickr.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('plugins/flatpickr/lang/vn.js') }}"></script>
@endsection

@section('custom-scripts')
    <script>
        function formatTooltip(tooltipItem) {
            let value = tooltipItem.raw;
            let formattedValue = new Intl.NumberFormat('vi-VN', {
                style: 'currency',
                currency: 'VND'
            }).format(value);
            return `${tooltipItem.dataset.label}: ${formattedValue}`;
        }

        function dashboard() {
            return {
                customRange: false,
                startDate: '',
                endDate: '',
                selectedDate: '',
                totalSales: {
                    today: '',
                    week: '',
                    month: '',
                    year: '',
                },
                recentOrders: [],
                topProducts: [],
                lowStockProducts: [],
                salesChartData: {
                    labels: [],
                    revenue: [],
                    cost: [],
                    profit: []
                },
                categoryChartData: {
                    labels: [],
                    data: []
                },
                brandChartData: {
                    labels: [],
                    data: []
                },
                salesChart: null,
                categoryChart: null,
                brandChart: null,
                timeRange: 'today',
                timeRangePicker: null,
                orderByStatus: [],
                init() {
                    this.fetchDashboardData();
                    this.initFlatpickr();
                    this.$watch('timeRange', (value) => {
                        if (value !== 'custom') {
                            this.fetchDashboardData();
                        }
                    });
                    this.$watch('startDate', () => {
                        if (this.customRange && this.startDate && this.endDate) {
                            this.fetchDashboardData();
                        }
                    });
                    this.$watch('endDate', () => {
                        if (this.customRange && this.startDate && this.endDate) {
                            this.fetchDashboardData();
                        }
                    });
                    this.$watch('customRange', (value) => {
                        if (!value) {
                            this.startDate = '';
                            this.endDate = '';
                            this.timeRangePicker?.clear();
                        }
                    });
                },
                fetchDashboardData() {
                    const url = `{{ route('admin.dashboardData') }}?timeRange=${this.timeRange}&startDate=${this.startDate}&endDate=${this.endDate}`;
                    fetch(url, {headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'}})
                        .then(response => response.json())
                        .then(data => {
                            this.totalSales.revenue = `${data.totalSales.revenue}`;
                            this.totalSales.cost = `${data.totalSales.cost}`;
                            this.totalSales.profit = `${data.totalSales.profit}`;

                            this.recentOrders = data.recentOrders;
                            this.topProducts = data.topProducts;
                            this.lowStockProducts = data.lowStockProducts;
                            this.orderByStatus = data.orderByStatus;

                            this.salesChartData.labels = data.salesChartData.labels;
                            this.salesChartData.revenue = data.salesChartData.revenue;
                            this.salesChartData.cost = data.salesChartData.cost;
                            this.salesChartData.profit = data.salesChartData.profit;

                            this.categoryChartData.labels = data.salesByCategory.labels;
                            this.categoryChartData.data = data.salesByCategory.data;

                            this.brandChartData.labels = data.salesByBrand.labels;
                            this.brandChartData.data = data.salesByBrand.data;

                            this.updateSalesChart();
                            this.updateCategoryChart();
                            this.updateBrandChart();
                        });
                },
                updateSalesChart() {
                    const ctx = document.getElementById('salesChart').getContext('2d');

                    if (this.salesChart) {
                        this.salesChart.destroy();
                    }

                    this.salesChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'bar',
                        data: {
                            labels: this.salesChartData.labels,
                            datasets: [
                                {
                                    label: 'Doanh thu',
                                    data: this.salesChartData.revenue,
                                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                                    borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                                    borderWidth: 1
                                },
                                {
                                    label: 'Chi phí',
                                    data: this.salesChartData.cost,
                                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                                    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                                    borderWidth: 1
                                },
                                {
                                    label: 'Lợi nhuận',
                                    data: this.salesChartData.profit,
                                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                                    borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                                    borderWidth: 1,
                                    type: 'line'
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        options: {
                            scales: {
                                y: {
                                    beginAtZero: true
                                }
                            },
                            plugins: {
                                tooltip: {
                                    callbacks: {
                                        label: formatTooltip
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        }
                    });
                },
                updateCategoryChart() {
                    const ctx = document.getElementById('categoryChart').getContext('2d');

                    if (this.categoryChart) {
                        this.categoryChart.destroy();
                    }

                    this.categoryChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'pie',
                        data: {
                            labels: this.categoryChartData.labels,
                            datasets: [
                                {
                                    label: 'Doanh thu',
                                    data: this.categoryChartData.data,
                                    backgroundColor: this.categoryChartData.labels.map(() => `rgba(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)}, ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)}, ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)}, 0.2)`),
                                    borderColor: this.categoryChartData.labels.map(() => `rgba(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)}, ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)}, ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)}, 1)`),
                                    borderWidth: 1
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        options: {
                            plugins: {
                                tooltip: {
                                    callbacks: {
                                        label: formatTooltip
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        }
                    });
                },
                updateBrandChart() {
                    const ctx = document.getElementById('brandChart').getContext('2d');

                    if (this.brandChart) {
                        this.brandChart.destroy();
                    }

                    this.brandChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'pie',
                        data: {
                            labels: this.brandChartData.labels,
                            datasets: [
                                {
                                    label: 'Doanh thu',
                                    data: this.brandChartData.data,
                                    backgroundColor: this.brandChartData.labels.map(() => `rgba(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)}, ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)}, ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)}, 0.2)`),
                                    borderColor: this.brandChartData.labels.map(() => `rgba(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)}, ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)}, ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)}, 1)`),
                                    borderWidth: 1
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        options: {
                            plugins: {
                                tooltip: {
                                    callbacks: {
                                        label: formatTooltip
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        }
                    });
                },
                initFlatpickr() {
                    this.timeRangePicker = flatpickr(this.$refs.datepicker, {
                        onChange: ([startDate, endDate]) => {
                            if (startDate && endDate) {
                                this.startDate = flatpickr.formatDate(startDate, 'Y-m-d');
                                this.endDate = flatpickr.formatDate(endDate, 'Y-m-d');
                            }
                        },
                        locale: "vn",
                        mode: "range",
                        altInput: true,
                        conjunction: " - ",
                        maxDate: "today",
                        altFormat: "d/m/Y",
                        dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
                    });
                },
            }
        }
    </script>
@endsection

This is admin.layouts.app
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
    <title>Admin Dashboard - Product Management</title>
    {{--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('AdminLTE/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css') }}">--}}
    <script src="{{ asset('plugins/tailwindcss/tailwindcss.min.css') }}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('plugins/fontawesome/css/all.min.css') }}"/>
    <script src="{{ asset('plugins/alpinejs/alpine.min.js') }}" defer></script>

    @yield('vendor-styles')

    @yield('custom-styles')
</head>
<body class="bg-gray-100">

<!-- Sidebar -->
@include('admin.layouts.includes.sidebar')

<!-- Main Content -->
<div class="flex-1 flex flex-col">
    <!-- Navbar -->
    @include('admin.layouts.includes.header')

    <!-- Breadcrumbs -->
    <nav class="bg-gray border-b border-gray-200">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-3 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <ol class="flex items-center space-x-4">
                @yield('breadcrumbs')
            </ol>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Main Section -->
    <main class="flex-1 bg-gray-100">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-6 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </main>

    <!-- Footer -->
    @include('admin.layouts.includes.footer')
</div>
<script src="{{ asset('plugins/htmx/htmx.js') }}"></script>

@yield('vendor-scripts')

@yield('custom-scripts')
</body>
</html>

Issue:
The charts render correctly with Alpine.js 2.8.2 but fail with Alpine.js 3.x, showing the error mentioned above.What could be causing this issue with Alpine.js 3.x, and how can I resolve it?
Environment:

Laravel Version: 9.x
Alpine.js Version: 3.14.1
Chart.js Version: 4.4.3

Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

In AlpineJs v3 the init() method of the data-object, if present,  is executed automatically at the startup.
In your main <div> you specify x-init="init()" (probably because the code was designed for AlpineJs v2 which didn't support this feature), so the init() method is executed two times and this causes the error.
You can verify this situation adding a console.log in the init():
init() {
   console.log ("init executed", Date.now());

   .....

To solve the problem remove x-init="init()" from the main <div>

EDIT
If the problem occurs again when you choose a date range it is because you have set a $watch on both ends of the range and this again causes two calls to fetchDashboardData() in rapid succession.
To solve this in a simple way, a possible solution is to group the dates' limits into a single object, define a single $watch on this object and then perform a cumulative assignment in the datepicker callback:

function dashboard() {

    return {

        customRange: false,
        // startDate: '',   <~~~ removed
        // endDate: '',     <~~~ removed
        dateRange: {startDate: '', endDate: ''}, //   <~~~ added
    
        .....

        init() {

           .....

           //this.$watch('startDate', () => {  <~~~ removed
           //   
           //   if (this.customRange && this.startDate && this.endDate) {
           //       this.fetchDashboardData();
           //   }
           //});
           //
           //this.$watch('endDate', () => { <~~~ removed
           //   
           //   if (this.customRange && this.startDate && this.endDate) {
           //       this.fetchDashboardData();
           //   }
           //});


           this.$watch('dateRange', () => {   //   <~~~ added

               if (this.customRange && this.dateRange.startDate && this.dateRange.endDate) {
                   this.fetchDashboardData();
               }
           });

           .....
        },

        .....

        initFlatpickr() {

            this.timeRangePicker = flatpickr(this.$refs.datepicker, {

                onChange: ([startDate, endDate]) => {

                    if (startDate && endDate) {

                        // this.startDate = flatpickr.formatDate(startDate, 'Y-m-d'); <~~~ removed
                        // this.endDate = flatpickr.formatDate(endDate, 'Y-m-d'); <~~~ removed

                        this.dateRange = {  // <~~~ added
                            startDate: flatpickr.formatDate(startDate, 'Y-m-d'),
                            endDate: flatpickr.formatDate(endDate, 'Y-m-d')
                         }
                    }
                },

                ..... 

Now every reference to this.startDate and this.endDate must be susbstituted with this.dateRange.startDate and this.dateRange.endDate

EDIT 2
All the problems encountered arise from the fact that the charts are quickly destroyed and redrawn when they have not yet finished drawing. Since animations are active by default, drawing charts may take longer than expected.
In previous cases the redrawing of the charts resulted from code design errors, while now the problem occurs due to a user interaction that must be managed.
The simplest solution is to disable the animations: add the animation key under options  in the configuration object of each chart and assign it the value false:
.....

options: {

    animation: false,

    .....


A more complex solution is to inhibit the inputs while charts are being drawn. To achieve this we can:

add in the AlpineJs-object a property that tracks the state of the the charts:

.....
lowStockProducts: [],
animating: {sales: false, categs: false, brand: false}, // <~~~ added
.....


add in the AlpineJs-object a function that returns the current cumulative state:

.....
init() {
    .....
},

animationInProgress() { // <~~~ added
    return this.animating.sales  ||  this.animating.categs  ||  this.animating.brand;
},

.....    


in every function that draws a chart initialize the related variable to true, then in the options of the configuration object add a callback to reset to false the variable on the animation complete. For example:

.....

updateSalesChart() {
    .....

    this.animating.sales = true; //   <~~~ added

    this.salesChart = new Chart(ctx, {

        .....

        options: {

            animation: {             //   <~~~ added
                onComplete: () => {
                    this.animating.sales = false;
                }
            },
    
        .....


finally in every button and in every control that must be inhibited during the drawing of the charts add the :disabled attribute, for example:

.....

<button @click="...."
        :class="....."
        .....
        :disabled="animationInProgress()"  {{-- <~~~ added --}}
>
    Hôm nay
</button>
.....

To be picky you could also disable the datepicker by adding a $watch() in the init() method:
this.$watch('animating', () => {
    this.timeRangePicker.set("clickOpens", !this.animationInProgress());
});


Thank you so much. I followed your method, and it worked, but when I press the filter button by time range, it occasionally errors as before. I use $watch to listen for changes in the time range filter to fetch data and update the chart.

This is a related but different issue, a new request should be opened ;-) See the update to my answer

It also encounters the above errors when I select time ranges such as "today", "thisMonth", "thisYear" ...etc. These values are stored in the "timeRange" state. It works for the first few times when changing the filter, but then it crashes, or it crashes immediately if I change the filter too quickly. I did not encounter this issue in version 2x; in version 2x, I could switch filters very quickly and it still worked fine. I am not a frontend developer and this is my first time using Alpine.js. I have read their documentation on the changes in version 3x but still haven't found a solution.

Keeping adding questions to the same request is not good practice.
If you still need more help you must open another request. Bear in mind that I am also predominantly a backend developer :-)

Thank you very much, it worked when I added animation: false. I'm wondering why this error didn't occur in Alpine.js 2.x. Is there a difference in the lifecycle or DOM handling?

There are some differences, however I have used version 2 very little. Maybe if you have updated Chart.js too it could depend on that
